# How to redeclare variables with the same name but belonging to different files in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, variable-declaration

I am loading two js files within an HTML page where both files contain the declaration of variables with the same name. I would like to know if there is a way to declare two variables with the same name other than using closures in javascript?

Comment: You can't. There is never a good reason to do it

Comment: You certainly need to limit the scope of the variables in some way, otherwise there would be no way to tell them apart. What that scope needs to be depends on what you want to do with the variables and where they need to be available. Or you could just rename one of them, if they both need to be global

Comment: @Andrew, why not? if I'd like to name whatever element I get from the dom an element no matter its type, why should I name it differently?

Comment: @ADyson Actually I am limiting the scope by closing the content of each file in one single main function, and this does the trick. However, I'd like to know if there's other possible ways?

Comment: @AbdouBestmood When you write code, don't think short term. Think long. 6 months from now, how digestible will your code be? You are only human, and if you name things the same across files you're opening up yourself to a slew of mistakes when you forget what is where.

Answer (score 2):

Your only option is to store them inside objects - variables with the same name in the same scope will be overridden every time. Change that in your JS files.

Instead of:

```
var aVariable = 42;
```

Do this:

```
var contents = { aVariable, anotherVariable, /* ...All the variables which have the same names */ };
```

And make sure the name `contents` is unique for each file.

Comment: Actually I am limiting the scope by closing the content of each file in one single main function, and this does the trick. However, I'd like to know if there's other possible ways? Like in PHP or C++, you can take profit of namespace feature to apply this matter, is it possible in Js? I have to mention that I am using ES6.